# Given a 2D list of print range based on column

Tags: python, list

I currently have a 2D list. The list will always be 2 rows but it can be multiple columns

`idx = [[0,4],[2, 6]] or idx = [[0,4,2,7],[2,6,5,10]]`

and I need to generate a range based on the column, where the first row indicates the lower bound and the second row indicates the upper bound, inclusively.

For example on the first column `idx[0]` it should generate `0,1,2` and the second `idx[1]` should generate `4,5,6` and so on.

This is my code for a list `idx = [1,2]` but I don't know how to do it for 2d list.

```
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        for j in range(idx[i]):
            print(j)
```

Comment: Please clarify what output you're expecting for each example. Why would `0, 4, 2, 7` or `2,6,5,10` result in only 3 numbers?

Comment: Also "should generate 4,5,6 and so on"? 1) Where did 3 go? 2) Ranges default starting from zero, so what's deciding your starting point

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a way to pair up the corresponding numbers in each row, it's a good idea to use `zip` here.

```py
idx = [[0, 4, 2, 7], [2, 6, 5, 10]]
for lower, upper in zip(*idx):
    print(list(range(lower, upper + 1))) # upper limit inclusive
    # or create an output list and append to it
```

From Python `help` text,

> The zip object yields n-length tuples, where n is the number of iterables passed as positional arguments to zip().  The i-th element in every tuple comes from the i-th iterable argument to zip().  This continues until the shortest argument is exhausted.

You can find more information about `zip` by typing `help(zip)` in any Python interpreter.